Are there technical reasons why a laptop with a 360Hz display only has 60Hz and 360Hz modes but no intermediate ones?
I don’t know if all manufacturers do this, but Gigabyte in their Aorus 17 2022 lineup made only two screen modes available: 60Hz and 360Hz.
I know about the existence of programs like CRU for creating custom refresh rate modes, but before using them I questioned myself: why the manufacturer made this strict lock on only two modes, 60Hz and 360Hz, why there are no intermediate ones?
And by the way, how do display manufacturers (not just for laptops) determine which modes are supported by the display? What does "support" for a certain refresh rate means after all? I mean when we're talking about intermediate values between the minimum and maximum frequency.
In short, I’m interested in the theoretical aspect, and if anyone knows, please share the information. But the practical question is:
Are there any disadvantages or risks (hardware or software problems) in creating a custom resolution through third-party software like CRU, for example, 120Hz, 100Hz, 75Hz on a laptop that by default only supports 60 and 360 Hz modes? What are the possible risks?
Another practical question is: how do I choose a proper custom refresh rate? Should I set it to a round number like 100Hz, or can I choose something like 99Hz if I prefer?
P.S. I'm asking about this because I'd like to reduce energy consumption when unplugged, since 360Hz consumes approximately twice as much energy as 60Hz, and 60Hz is eye-bleeding when you're used to higher refresh rates. Will I achieve my goal, how do you think?
Thanks.

This has been noted on Linux as a bug: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/i915/kernel/-/issues/6484, https://forum.manjaro.org/t/missing-a-refresh-rate-since-update-gigabyte-aorus-17-laptop/101074 . Try updating OS, or try another OS. It might also need the color mode changed to access other rates: https://www.reddit.com/r/gigabytegaming/comments/opx5d2/aorus_fi27qx_monitors_refresh_rate_cannot_be_set/

@DrMoishePippik looks like people there can't set maximum refresh rate on their laptop/monitor. That's not the case, since 360 Hz works fine. I need kinda reverse, when the only 60 and 360 Hz available, I need to set it 100 Hz for example. And my OS is Windows. It's not a software problem, it's about workaround of manufacturer limitations, since Gigabyte added only two modes to device BIOS/EDID.
